# How to use `&` in match expression?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, expression

In [Symbol and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/index), the symbol `&` is used for:

> Links: [Match Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions)
>
> - Computes the address of a mutable value, for use when interoperating with other languages.
> - Used in AND patterns.

I've looked at the Match Expressions page but I didn't see any AND patterns. How can I use the `&` patterns?

Comment: See  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching

Comment: @JohnPalmer Could you post an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen it used before. That's a real language trivia question.

Comment: @scrwtp - I agree - although it looks like it could be used instead of when guards and be quite nice inc some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The and pattern syntax looks like the following:

```
(a, b) & (_, "test")
```

It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#and-pattern).